# How to manually set z-axis values in a 3d plot?

Tags: plotting

I'm plotting an hemisphere with

```
radius = 5;
Height = 0.2;
SphericalPlot3D[ radius, { θ, 0, π/2}, { ϕ, 0, 2 π}, 
                 BoxRatios -> { 1, 1, ((0.5 Height)/(radius) + 0.03)}]
```

and I'm using `BoxRatios` to flatten the hemisphere so that it has a "height" of 0.2.
Is it possible to manually write/show the $z$-axis values so the visible range is not `{ 0, radius}`
but `{ 0, 0.2}`?

Comment: Why not just plot the ellipsoid? `SphericalPlot3D[h r/Sqrt[r^2 Cos[θ]^2 + h^2 Sin[θ]^2], {θ, 0, π/2}, {ϕ, 0, 2 π}]`

Comment: @SimonWoods: thank you, what you've written is very interessing. I don't know much about formulas with polar coordinates, that's why I can't use well SphericalPlot3D...is there a site where they're all listed? So that I can learn more...

Comment: @Kuba : yes, I've just confirmed the answers. They're what I need. No matter if it looks flattened, it's more important to show certain values on the z-axis...I know I was asking for "strange" things...but it's the first time I've approached to mathematica and I'm making a mess! thank you anyway

Comment: @LoryLory ok, thank you ;)

Comment: @LoryLory, [MathWorld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Ellipsoid.html) is quite good for that kind of thing, there is also Wikipedia of course.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you want to show the label `"0.2"` at the $z$-value `5`.

The option `Ticks` allows you to do this. Here is an example:

```
 Plot3D[ 5 Sin[x y], { x, 0, π}, { y, 0, π}, 
         Ticks -> { Automatic, Automatic, {-5, -3, 0, {5, "0.2"}}}]
```